# Why is PropertyDataCollection object persisting multiple records to database

Tags: c#, collections, wmi, biztalk

I have a utility that reads the status of MicrosoftBizTalk Server resources .. specifically the ReceiveLocation component. My problem is that the program is submitting multiple entries of each item i.e each item in the data returned is being multiplied by 25 such that instead of persisting only 5 rows the data being persisted is 125. So for example instead of having just 1 row for my first row returned i have 25.

This is my program :

```
public List<BizTalk> GetBizTalkServicesStatistics()
    {

    
        List<BizTalk> model = new List<BizTalk>();

        try
        {
            //Create the WMI search object.
            ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher();

            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions
            {

                Username = "+username+",
                Password = "+password+",
                Authority = "+domain+"
            };

            
            var server = "+server+";
            // create the scope node so we can set the WMI root node correctly.
            ManagementScope Scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + server + "\\root\\MicrosoftBizTalkServer", options);
            Searcher.Scope = Scope;

            // Build a Query to enumerate the MSBTS_ReceiveLocation instances if an argument
            // is supplied use it to select only the matching RL.

                //if (args.Length == 0)
                SelectQuery Query = new SelectQuery();               
                Query.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM MSBTS_ReceiveLocation";
                //          else
                //Query.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM MSBTS_ReceiveLocation WHERE Name = '" + args[0] + "'";


            // Set the query for the searcher.
            Searcher.Query = Query;

            // Execute the query and determine if any results were obtained.
            ManagementObjectCollection QueryCol = Searcher.Get();

            // Use a bool to tell if we enter the for loop
            // below because Count property is not supported
            bool ReceiveLocationFound = false;

            // Enumerate all properties.
            foreach (ManagementBaseObject envVar in QueryCol)
            {
                // There is at least one Receive Location
                ReceiveLocationFound = true;

                PropertyDataCollection envVarProperties = envVar.Properties;
               
                foreach (PropertyData envVarProperty in envVarProperties)
                {
                    BizTalk bizTalk = new BizTalk();
                    bizTalk.Name = Convert.ToString(envVar["Name"]);
                    bizTalk.TransportType = Convert.ToString(envVar["AdapterName"]);
                    bizTalk.Uri = Convert.ToString(envVar["InboundTransportURL"]);
                    bizTalk.Status = Convert.ToString(envVar["Name"]);
                    bizTalk.ReceiveHandler = Convert.ToString(envVar["HostName"]);
                    bizTalk.ReceivePort = Convert.ToString(envVar["ReceivePortName"]);
                    bizTalk.RunDate = DateTime.Now;
                    bizTalk.ApplicationId = 24;
                    bizTalk.ServerId = 8;
                    bizTalk.InstanceName = "FBCZOP";                                          
                    model.Add(bizTalk);
                    
                }
            }

            if (!ReceiveLocationFound)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No receive locations found matching the specified name.");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.SendErrorToText(excep);
        }

        return model;
    }
```

Save Function

```
public void SaveStatistics(BizTalk entity)
    {
        List<BizTalk> ServerInfo = new List<BizTalk>();
        ServerInfo = GetBizTalkServicesStatistics();
        foreach (var di in ServerInfo)
        {
            entity.RunDate = di.RunDate;
            entity.Name = di.Name;
            entity.Status = di.Status;
            entity.Uri = di.Uri;
            entity.InstanceName = di.InstanceName;
            entity.ReceivePort = di.ReceivePort;
            entity.TransportType= di.TransportType;
            entity.RunDate = DateTime.Now;
            entity.ReceiveHandler = di.ReceiveHandler;                
            entity.ServerId = entity.ServerId;
            entity.ApplicationId = entity.ApplicationId;
            appEntities.BizTalk.Add(entity);
            appEntities.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

When i step through the code variable envVarProperties shows record count as 125 under envVarProperties << ResultsView :
[Link 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tdzu-6OIoyRNEpLgeqntX8lCnnqNBZAy/view?usp=sharing)

whilst QueryCol variable shows count of 5 :

[Link 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TdkPFD43awRBfQOceZ4luZlpNU7rLe03/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: if my solution below assisted you please mark it as the answer.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're iterating an extra time in your `GetBizTalkServicesStatistics()` method.

Remove the foreach loop that starts with `foreach (PropertyData envVarProperty in envVarProperties).`  This is looping through each property the object has (All 25 properties) for each instance (5 instances)... 25 * 5 = 125 values you are retrieving.  You only want to iterate through your instances and pull the properties you want.  That way you end up with 5 objects in your model object.

I'd suggest maybe something like this (untested because I don't have BizTalk)

```
public List<BizTalk> GetBizTalkServicesStatistics()
        {

            List<BizTalk> model = new List<BizTalk>();

            try
            {
                //Create the WMI search object.
                ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions
                {
                    Username = "+username+",
                    Password = "+password+",
                    Authority = "+domain+"
                };

                var server = "+server+";

                // create the scope node so we can set the WMI root node correctly.
                ManagementScope Scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + server + "\\root\\MicrosoftBizTalkServer", options);

                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM MSBTS_ReceiveLocation"));

                // Enumerate all properties.
                foreach (ManagementObject instance in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    {
                        BizTalk bizTalk = new BizTalk();
                        bizTalk.Name = instance.Properties["Name"]?.Value?.ToString();
                        bizTalk.TransportType = instance.Properties["AdapterName"]?.Value?.ToString();
                        bizTalk.Uri = instance.Properties["InboundTransportURL"]?.Value?.ToString();
                        bizTalk.Status = instance.Properties["Name"]?.Value?.ToString();
                        bizTalk.ReceiveHandler = instance.Properties["HostName"]?.Value?.ToString();
                        bizTalk.ReceivePort = instance.Properties["ReceivePortName"]?.Value?.ToString();
                        bizTalk.RunDate = DateTime.Now;
                        bizTalk.ApplicationId = 24;
                        bizTalk.ServerId = 8;
                        bizTalk.InstanceName = "FBCZOP";
                        model.Add(bizTalk);
                    }
                }

                // Determine  
                if (model.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No receive locations found matching the specified name.");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                ExceptionLogger.SendErrorToText(excep);
            }

            return model;
        }
```

Also, this can be simplified more if you remove the connectionoptions (unless you are hard coding credentials which is highly advised against).  If you are just using the identity of the executing user, that data is not needed.

-Paul

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same entity 25 times and overwrite its properties by reference. You need to initialize a new entity inside your loop:

```
foreach (var di in ServerInfo)
        {
            var entity = new BizTalk();
            entity.RunDate = di.RunDate;
            entity.Name = di.Name;
            entity.Status = di.Status;
            entity.Uri = di.Uri;
            entity.InstanceName = di.InstanceName;
            entity.ReceivePort = di.ReceivePort;
            entity.TransportType= di.TransportType;
            entity.RunDate = DateTime.Now;
            entity.ReceiveHandler = di.ReceiveHandler;                
            entity.ServerId = entity.ServerId;
            entity.ApplicationId = entity.ApplicationId;
            appEntities.BizTalk.Add(entity);
            appEn.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

As you don't show the code where "SaveStatistics" is called it's not sure this will fix your complete problem, but it's at least one method that does not do what you expect it to do.